# No route matches [DELETE] "/todo_lists/1/todo_items.9"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been following a tutorial to create a Todo list app using Ruby on Rails. [Click to view Todo app tutorial here](https://medium.com/@deallen7/how-to-build-a-todo-app-in-rails-e6571fcccac3)

As of now, I have created the TodoLists controller, TodoItems Controller and actions along with the respective models.

Here is my code:

todo_items_controller.rb:

```
class TodoItemsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_todo_list

  def create
    @todo_item = @todo_list.todo_items.new(todo_item_params)
    if @todo_item.save
      redirect_to todo_list_path(@todo_list)
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @todo_item = @todo_list.todo_items.find(params[:id])
    if @todo_item.destroy
      flash[:success] = "Todo List item was deleted."
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Todo List item could not be deleted."
    end
    redirect_to @todo_list
  end

  private
  def todo_item_params
    params.require(:todo_item).permit(:content)
  end

  def set_todo_list
    @todo_list = TodoList.find(params[:todo_list_id])
  end
end
```

Here is my routes.rb:

```
rails routes
                   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                              Controller#Action
                     root GET    /                                                                                        todo_lists#index
     todo_list_todo_items GET    /todo_lists/:todo_list_id/todo_items(.:format)                                           todo_items#index
                          POST   /todo_lists/:todo_list_id/todo_items(.:format)                                           todo_items#create
  new_todo_list_todo_item GET    /todo_lists/:todo_list_id/todo_items/new(.:format)                                       todo_items#new
 edit_todo_list_todo_item GET    /todo_lists/:todo_list_id/todo_items/:id/edit(.:format)                                  todo_items#edit
      todo_list_todo_item GET    /todo_lists/:todo_list_id/todo_items/:id(.:format)                                       todo_items#show
                          PATCH  /todo_lists/:todo_list_id/todo_items/:id(.:format)                                       todo_items#update
                          PUT    /todo_lists/:todo_list_id/todo_items/:id(.:format)                                       todo_items#update
                          DELETE /todo_lists/:todo_list_id/todo_items/:id(.:format)                                       todo_items#destroy
               todo_lists GET    /todo_lists(.:format)                                                                    todo_lists#index
                          POST   /todo_lists(.:format)                                                                    todo_lists#create
            new_todo_list GET    /todo_lists/new(.:format)                                                                todo_lists#new
           edit_todo_list GET    /todo_lists/:id/edit(.:format)                                                           todo_lists#edit
                todo_list GET    /todo_lists/:id(.:format)                                                                todo_lists#show
                          PATCH  /todo_lists/:id(.:format)                                                                todo_lists#update
                          PUT    /todo_lists/:id(.:format)                                                                todo_lists#update
                          DELETE /todo_lists/:id(.:format)                                                                todo_lists#destroy
```

I think the problem is here in the following code in `_todo_item.html.erb` 
 with "todo_item.id". Also, as I'm usually acquainted with simple `link_to`s such as `<%= link_to "Delete", article_path(@article), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure? } %>`, I'm not sure how the more complicated `link_to` is constructed especially `todo_list_todo_items_path(@todo_list, todo_item.id)`

_todo_item.html.erb:

```
<p><%= todo_item.content %></p>
<%= link_to "Delete", todo_list_todo_items_path(@todo_list, todo_item.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
```

1. Could someone point out the error in my code?
2. Explain the second part of the link_to tag that I mentioned above?

Thank you very much.

Comment: can you try this code: <%= link_to todo_list_todo_item_path(@todo_list, todo_item.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>

Comment: I tried it, but it is not working. The address looks like the following: `http://localhost:3000/todo_lists/1/todo_items.9`. I think it should look rather like this: `http://localhost:3000/todo_lists/1/todo_items/9`

Comment: can you push that project to github so we can check the code?

Comment: sure @Nezir, [here you go](https://github.com/jerof/todo)

Comment: What @Nezir has mentioned should work. Look closely. `todo_list_todo_item_path` not `todo_list_todo_items_path`

Comment: oh you have different branch... let me check

Comment: Can you give me rights to push my code to github todo-list branch?

Comment: @Nezir, I'd like to. But given that I'm quite new to coding, I'm not sure how.

Comment: @Nezir your solution worked. I tried `todo_list_todo_item_path` not `todo_list_todo_items_path`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your routes show:

```
  todo_list_todo_item GET    /todo_lists/:todo_list_id/todo_items/:id(.:format)                                       todo_items#show
                      PATCH  /todo_lists/:todo_list_id/todo_items/:id(.:format)                                       todo_items#update
                      PUT    /todo_lists/:todo_list_id/todo_items/:id(.:format)                                       todo_items#update
                      DELETE /todo_lists/:todo_list_id/todo_items/:id(.:format)                                       todo_items#destroy
```

So, the helper for the DELETE route is:

```
todo_list_todo_item_path
```

not

```
todo_list_todo_items_path
```

(note the change in 'item' vs 'items')

Your link code should be:

```
<%= link_to "Delete", todo_list_todo_item_path(@todo_list, todo_item.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
```

**To answer your second question part:**

Your routes show:

```
DELETE /todo_lists/:todo_list_id/todo_items/:id(.:format)
```

This route requires two parameters: the id of the **TodoList** and the id of the **TodoItem**. These are shown in the route as **:todo_list_id** and **:id**.

Note how in your controller you are first finding a TodoList by **params[:todo_list_id]** in the before_action, and then you are finding a TodoItem on the association by **params[:id]** in the action.

In your **link_to**, you have to pass both parameters.

The **Rails guide on Routing** is probably something you should read to gain a better understanding of how it all works: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: @user3772256 I'm very glad to hear that! When you get a moment, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have more errors in your projects. Here is your project fixed and pushed on my git repo: https://github.com/nezirz/todo-list

```
<%= link_to "DELETE - #{todo_item.content}", todo_list_todo_item_path(@todo_list, todo_item.id), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" } %>
```